# finding negative number closest to 0 in array (log n complexity)

Tags: c

I have a question: write a function that gets an ascending array of whole numbers and their size.
It is given that the array contains at least one negative number and one positive number, and I need to find the closest negative number to the number `0.`

for example: `[-30,-25,-18,-10,11,11,20,30]`

the function will return `-10.`

The problem is that I need to do it in `O(log n)` complexity and I don't know how to do this.
I made it only with `O(n).`

`

```
int f(int* arr, int size)
{
int i;
int result = arr[0];
for (i = 1;i < size;i++)
{
    if (arr[i] < 0 && result < arr[i])
        result = arr[i];
    else
        return result;
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: Since the array is guaranteed to be sorted, you can take advantage of that information.

Comment: You don't need to traverse the whole array. Traverse untill u get any whole number

Comment: Use a binary search?

Comment: Start in the middle and keep subdividing. Since it's sorted you know which side of the middle your answer will be in.

Comment: Nick and adapt std::lower_bound from a C++ standard library implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple C implementation of a binary search, which works in O(log n) time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    size_t bot = 0;
    size_t top = size;                 // it will never be top
    size_t dif;
    while((dif = top - bot) > 1) {
        size_t mid = bot + dif / 2;
        if(arr[mid] >= 0) {            // eliminate non-negatives
            top = mid;
        } 
        else {
            bot = mid;
        }
    }
    return arr[bot];
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { -30, -25, -18, -10, 11, 11, 20, 30 };
    size_t size = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];  //parentheses only needed for types
    printf("%d\n", find(arr, size));
}
```

I like to use a binary search so that the `top` element is never a candidate.
Program output:

```
-10
```

Comment: bot + top is vulnerable to overflow. As you’re aiming for robustness you should address. See how std::midpoint is implemented in a c++20 standard library implementation.

Comment: @Bathsheba was just attending to that.

Comment: Upvoted in good faith - I’m sure you will!

Comment: Since it is given the array contains at least one positive number, `top` may be initialized to `size-1`. (This is an exercise in the complement of the stated problem: Instead of finding the greatest negative number, find the least positive optimization.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil true, beginning with `top = size - 1` may save one iteration in some cases.

Comment: Oh no, this one has the attention of @EricPostpischil!! Which means you need to sharpen up the midpoint function.

Comment: I would be inclined to replace the entire `if` statement with `*(arr[mid] >= 0 ? &top : &bot) = mid;`, but will take pity on the students. (In C++, you can do it without the `*` and `&`, but C does not allow lvalues here.)

Comment: It is functionally equivalent. My own preference is not to use ternary operators. If find code easier to read and maintain with `if ... else`.

Comment: Consider that `if (e) a = x; else b = x;` is identical to `e ? a = x : b  = x;` in function and in essential grammar. Therefore, there is no objective reason to prefer one over the other; any preference is opinion. Then consider that `(e ? a : b) = x;` is objectively a reduction from `e ? a = x : b = x;`; it eliminates repetition and condenses the part of the expression that varies. In C, the need for `&` and `*` gives a potential reason to avoid this, but, in C++, we can say it is objectively a better expression, and therefore we should try to adjust our preferences to favor it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am not writing in C++, and as you say, your preference for `*(arr[mid] >= 0 ? &top : &bot) = mid;` is opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible way

```
int f( int *n, int size )
{
    int low = 0, mid, high = size-1;
        
    while( (mid = (low+high)/2) && n[mid] * n[mid+1] > 0 ) n[mid] < 0 ? (low = mid) : (high = mid);
    
    return n[mid] ? n[mid] : n[mid-1];
}
```

I posted it condensed to give you something to do. Rewrite it properly using `if else` and `do while`.

The program uses `min`, `max` and `mid` as indexes for the array `n[]`.

`min` is set to 0 and will always be the index of a negative number, `max` is set to `size-1` and will always be the index of a positive number or of a 0. `mid` will always be between them (or exactly them).

The loop breaks when find an element (that is `n[mid]`) such that multiplied for the next one gives a negative number or zero.

Then the function returns `n[mid]`, unless it is 0, in this case it returns the element before `n[mid]`.

Note that if the array can contain dupes, then you need to handle the case of multiple 0s adding something like that at the end

```
while( !n[mid] ) --mid;
```

EDIT: I forgot to tell you that since the algorithm for the function is a [binary search](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm&ved=2ahUKEwjs4MXVifvtAhUQTxUIHU1sBnIQmhMwDXoECAYQAg&usg=AOvVaw1LkFEJqm3F1kteW4yaDdU-), it suits your time complexity requirements.